# Проверка находится ли в комментарии ответ на комментарий

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть комментарии, на них можно отвечать. Мне надо проверить содержит ли коментарий ответ или нет.

Что у меня получилось:

```
    let сomments = [{сomment_id: 1, product_id: 1, ...}, {сomment_id: 2, product_id: 1, ...}, .... ];
    let nested_comments = [{nested_id: 1, сomment_id: 1,product_id: 1},{nested_id: 2, сomment_id: 1, product_id: 1},...];
    for (let i = 0; i < nested_comments.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < сomments.length; j++) {
            if (сomments[j].сomment_id = nested_comments[i].сomment_id) {
                сomments[j]['nested comment'] = nested_comments[i];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(сomments)
```

Но у меня только последний комментарий выводиться.

Мне нужен результат:

```
{
    { 
        сomment_id: 1, 
        product_id: 1, 
        ...,
        nested comment: {
            {
                nested_id: 1,
                сomment_id: 1,
                product_id: 1,
                ...
            },
            {
                nested_id: 2,
                сomment_id: 1,
                product_id: 1,
                ...
            },
        }
    },
    { 
        сomment_id: 2, 
        product_id: 1, 
        ...,
        nested comment: {

        }
    }
}
```

То есть у первого комментария есть два ответа, у второго нет ни одного и так далее, может быть и 10 ответов.

Comment: А сторону сервера вы пишите? Если вы то скрин таблиц БД (интересующи только, конечно) добавьте и метод сервера, который отдает данные на клиент. Если не вы то скопируйте просто массив данных, получаемые на клиенте.

Comment: Данные я указал какие возвращаются, все работает отлично. Проблема в там что у меня не получается записать `nested_comments` в `сomments `, при условии что поле `сomment_id` содержиться в `nested_comments` и если оно равно полю `сomment_id` из `сomments `, тогда записать `nested_comments` в `сomments `

Comment: В условии одно `=` это нормально? `if (сomments[j].сomment_id = nested_comments[i].сomment_id)`, `nested comment` поменяйте на nested_comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 let сomments = [{сomment_id: 1, product_id: 1, comment: "asdasd"}, {сomment_id: 2, product_id: 1, comment: "asdasd"}];
    let nested_comments = [{nested_id: 1, сomment_id: 1,product_id: 1},{nested_id: 2, сomment_id: 1, product_id: 1}];
    сomments.forEach(el => {
      nested_comments.forEach(elem => {
        if (el.сomment_id === elem.сomment_id)
        if (el["nested_comments"] === undefined)
        {
          el["nested_comments"] = [];
          el.nested_comments.push(elem.nested_id);
        }
        else
        {
          el.nested_comments.push(elem.nested_id);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(сomments);
```